# Cannot choose apps to share with in Google Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, huawei-honor-6

When I click the "Share" button at bottom of the app description page, I do not get the usual sharing panel. Instead, it pastes the link to SMS, from where I have to copy, discard SMS option and then share it by mail (as an example). I end up doing three steps to share by mail, instead of a single click. Strangely, this happens only from Google Play Store. From all other apps, say ES File Explorer, I can choose and share the way I want to.

This behaviour started a few days back and I can't think of anything that could have triggered it. Searched in Play Store and Google settings but couldn't find any way to alter this behaviour. Other things which didn't help are reinstalling Play Store, uninstalling recently added apps, cleaning system and traces of leftover apps by SD Maid and cleaning Dalvik Cache.

This behaviour isn't driving me nuts but being unable to find the cause and fix is. Pointers on how to fix and what could have caused it are eagerly sought. I don't have access to laptop plus my Linux/coding knowledge is pretty much nil, so if it has to be command based, request something I could copy-paste on device terminal emulator.

Specs:

- Huawei Honor 6 (4.4.2) , rooted stock ROM
- Play Store Version 6.0.0 (reported as up to date in settings)

Comment: I couldn't repro on Nexus 5, Marshmallow 6.0, Play Store 6.0.0. Not sure if it's version-specific bug (since yours is KitKat).

Comment: @AndrewT.. but it was working fine till few days ago. That is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identified the cause.

It is known that Xposed clashes with heavily modded stock UI. That's one reason Xposed version 2.5.1 is the last version which supports without breaking theming engine. Xposed has a setting "Disabled Resource Hooks". If you uncheck it, this problem doesn't occur, but if you check it,it recurrs.

In my case, I don't want to uncheck it as it breaks other things in UI, so it's easier to live with the problem. Though why this should only happen with Google Play Store is unexplained